# sklearn's KMeans: Cluster centers and cluster means differ. Numerical Imprecision?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I've noticed that when using sklearn.cluster.KMeans to obtain clusters, the cluster centers, from the method .cluster_centers_, and computing means manually for each cluster don't seem to give exactly the same answer.

For small sample sizes the difference is very small and probably within float imprecision. But for larger samples:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.normal(size=5000)
x_z = (x - x.mean() / x.std()).reshape(5000,1)
cluster=KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(x_z)

df = pd.DataFrame(x_z)
df['label'] =  cluster.labels_

difference = np.abs(df.groupby('label').mean() - cluster.cluster_centers_)
print(difference)
```

[[ 0.00217333]
[ 0.00223798]]

Doing the same thing for different sample sizes: [image]

This seems too much to be floating point imprecision. Are cluster centers not means, or what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it may be related to the tolerance of `KMeans`. The default value is `1e-4`, so setting a lower value, i.e. `tol=1e-8` gives:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.normal(size=5000)
x_z = (x - x.mean() / x.std()).reshape(5000,1)
cluster=KMeans(n_clusters=2, tol=1e-8).fit(x_z)

df = pd.DataFrame(x_z)
df['label'] =  cluster.labels_

difference = np.abs(df.groupby('label').mean() - cluster.cluster_centers_)
print(difference)

                    0
label                
0      9.99200722e-16
1      1.11022302e-16
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good find. Figured this out just a few seconds later.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it. I'm still a bit puzzled how something as simple as computing the mean over an exactly defined set of observations could go wrong with high tolerance, but I guess I need to look into how the algorithm actually works